# Prolog, check divisibility in Peano arithmetic

Tags: prolog, multiplication, successor-arithmetics

I need to check if first given term (for example `s(s(nul))` (or 2)) is dividable by the second term, (for example `s(nul)` (or 1)).

What I want to do is multiply given term by two and then check if that term is smaller or equal to the other term (if it is equal - problem is solved).

So far I got this:

```
checkingIfDividable(X,X).
checkingIfDividable(X,Y) :-
    X > Y,
    multiplication(X,Y).

/* multiplication by two should occur here. 
   I can't figure it out. This solution does not work!*/
multiplication(Y):-
    YY is Y * 2,
    checkingIfDividable(X,YY).
```

I can't seem to figure out how to multiply a term by 2. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If `a = n*b, n > 0`, it is also `a = n*b = (1+m)*b = b + m*b, m >= 0`.

So if `a` is dividable by `b`, and `a = b+x`, then `x` is also dividable by `b`.

In Peano encoding, `n = 1+m` is written `n = s(m)`.

Take it from here.